# how to sort file by DD-MM-YYYY dates

Tags: date, sort

in a file containing :

```
...
18-11-2018:othercharacters
10-11-2018:othercharacters
03-10-2018:othercharacters
30-10-2018:othercharacters
27-09-2018:othercharacters
03-12-2018:othercharacters
...
```

the command :

```
sort -t- -k2 -k1
```

does not sort by date, what am I missing ?

Comment: Have you tried the `--debug` option to see what is happening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's one of the reasons why the recommended date format is YYYY-MM-DD.

`-k2` sorts on the portion of the line that starts with the second field, you need `-k2,2` to sort on the second field only, so:

```
sort -b -t- -k2,2 -k1,1
```

Or:

```
sort -b -k1.7,1.10 -k1.4,1.5 -k1.1,1.2
```

To sort first on year (7th to 10th character of the first field (counted after having ignored the leading blanks in that field with `-b`, and with the default field separator (transition from a non-blank to a blank))), then month then day.

Comment: thanks, just what I needed, and also for clarifying the -k argument

Comment: Or `sort -t- -k3n -k2n -k1n`.

Comment: "That's one of the reasons..." Yeah, but sometimes the output is not how you want it. You could use awk to reshuffle and sort, but sort in this case is just shorter. THX BTW, handy

Comment: `sort -b -k1.7,1.10 -k1.4,1.5 -k1.1,1.2` works to me to find recent modified files, i.e.: `find . -type f -printf "\n%Td-%Tm-%TY %TT %p" | sort -b -k1.7,1.10 -k1.4,1.5 -k1.1,1.2 -r`

Answer (score 0):

Using `-k2` with `sort` would make the utility use the whole line from the 2nd field on as the sort key. Unless this sort key is not unique, the later `-k1` would never be used.  To only use the second field as the first sorting key, then use `-k2,2`.  Adding `-k1` or `-k1,1` to that would not be needed as `sort` would use the whole line as the sorting key by default if the other sorting keys are not unique (and "the whole line" starts with the first field).

In other words, the following three commands are equivalent:

```bash
sort -t - -k 2,2 -k 1,1 file
sort -t - -k 2,2 -k 1 file
sort -t - -k 2,2 file
```

---

The following is a more generic solution.

Assuming that the data may be parsed as a "simple" header-less CSV file that uses `:` as the field delimiter, we may convert the date in the first field into a Unix timestamp in a new field, sort by that new field, and then drop the field.  This is sometimes called a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform).

Using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```bash
$ mlr --csvlite --fs : -N put '$key = strptime($1,"%d-%m-%Y")' then sort -f key then cut -x -f key file
27-09-2018:othercharacters
03-10-2018:othercharacters
30-10-2018:othercharacters
10-11-2018:othercharacters
18-11-2018:othercharacters
03-12-2018:othercharacters
```

The `put` expression creates a named field called `key` with the result of the `strptime()` call.  This would be a Unix timestamp like `1542499200.000000` ("2018-11-18") denoting the number of seconds since the start of 1970-01-01.  We then use the `sort` operation on this field and drop it with `cut -x`.

Answer (score 0):

As a more general year/month/day sorting solution you could replace the initial colon (`:`) with a colon+dash (`-:`), sort by fields 3, 2, 1, and then replace the colon+dash with just a colon to end. (This isolates the year as a separate field from the remainer of the line so that it can be sorted independently of the line. It does assume that `-:` will not occur in the first three fields of the data.)

```
sed 's/:/-:/' file | sort -t'-' -k3,3 -k2,2 -k1,1 | sed 's/-:/:/'
```

While I appreciate that you don't appear to need to sort years with the data set you have shown us, this is one approach to generalising the problem.